# How to "autodiscover" a different location for the admin.py file?

Tags: python, django

I think it makes sense to organize my Django apps in a different way (by protocol):

```
myapp
    apps.py
    models.py
    utilities.py
    html
        admin.py
        urls.py
        views.py
    rest
        serializers.py
        urls.py
        views.py
    graphql
        etc
```

This would move the `admin.py` file into the `html` folder, but sadly `autodiscover` does not seem to find it anywhere else than in the `myapp` folder. Is there a way to point to the correct location: perhaps in `apps.py`? I am sure a symlink would work, but not really what I am after.

Comment: Im pretty sure you can just import it at the top (or bottom of models.py) `from html import admin`  (you will probably need an `__init__.py`)

Comment: The idea would work, but that results in an error for imports from `models` to `admin`. I think it has to do with circular imports.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing magic about either admin.py or autodiscover. All admin.py does is run any register calls on import, and all autodiscover does is look for an admin.py file in each installed app and import it. There's nothing to stop you importing your admin.py in its custom location from somewhere else, eg the models or views files.

Answer (score 0):

This was somewhat tricky, but the comment by @Joran Beasley set me in the right direction.

For `admin.py` to be autodiscovered it needs to be either in the top level app folder, or be imported in a file. However... not every file works.

If you do `from .html import admin`

- into `__init__.py` or `apps.py`: django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
- into `models.py`: Results in an importerror from models into admin. I think due to the circular nature of the imports.

However the following works: `from . import admin` inside the `urls.py`. Make sure to add a comment that this import is needed for autodiscover purposes.